# Is there a way to automatically #define header files in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Since it's petty much mandatory that you do this, it seems like thered be a way to just have it done automatically.  It'd save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517287.aspx) that include these declarations.

An alternative is to write some [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) to ease insertion of header `#define` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have preprocessor directives that expand into other preprocessor directives.

But you can have a header that includes all the headers you need, and include only one header wherever you like.

Note that this might slow down compilation time, since the translation units will get bigger.